# Tag for the Technical Transition from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: discussion

Is there an existing tag for posts related to converting features of Magento 1 modules to Magento 2?  If not, can anyone think of a better tag to use than [module-converstion-1-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/module-converstion-1-2)?

Comment: I think you mean conversion? :)

Comment: @philwinkle I've address the spirit of your comment without showing weakness and removing the word transition

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- m1-to-m2
- m2-upgrade
- m2-db-upgrade
- m2-migration-tools

Comment: mmmm-wth-am-i-doing

Comment: What about these:

[ m2-migration | m2-module-migration | m2-extension-migration | m2-db-migration ]   

Just thinking that since there technically isn't a traditional "upgrade" path and using that verbiage may be confusing to some users or perhaps undercut the importance of understanding that given the changes in m2 it's more appropriate to consider the required effort a "re-write" and not an upgrade.  

PS - I love that the misspelled tag Alan links to is already applied to two questions!